# Go - "version" package and How it works?

Tags: go, versioning, ldflags

I am researching approaches to organize projects in different open source projects (for example `operator-framework/operator-sdk`) and sometime find `version` package with `version.go` file:

```
├── build
├── cmd
├── deploy
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── pkg
├── tools.go
└── version
    └── version.go
```

```
package version

var (
    Version = "0.0.1"
)
```

I tried to find how to use it to control application version, but found only approach  uses `-ldflags`.

Are exist other ways to use `version` package and `version.go` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are exists other ways to use version package and version.go file?

No.

Comment: How can I get `Version` value from `app`  (except of `fmt.Print(...)`)?

Comment: You cannot. Go binaries do not have per se a "version". They are just binaries which might or might not know and/or expose their "version".

Comment: that's mean if I want to maintain version of binaries I have to set "version" into `var` use  `-ldflags` when I build app and then get "version" from binaries use own implemented mechanism (for example `CLI` implemented with `cobra` library)?!

Comment: Yes, this is one possible way. A `version` variable set during build time via -ldflags and a `-version` flag printing `version` is common. Other things are possible too.